# delete gitlab backups file

Tags: docker, gitlab, backups

I am using docker to deploy my gitlab service, but gitlab does not delete the backups file, causing the file too big.

```
sudo docker run --detach \
    --hostname gitlab.deja.fashion \
    --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 2222:22 \
    --name gitlab \
    --restart always \
    -e GITLAB_BACKUP_SCHEDULE=daily \
    -e GITLAB_BACKUP_TIME=15:00 \
    -e GITLAB_BACKUP_EXPIRY=604800 \
    --volume /home/ubuntu/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
    --volume /home/ubuntu/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
    --volume /home/ubuntu/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
    gitlab/gitlab-ce:11.3.0-rc6.ce.0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is an error in backing up gitlab code to aws, the backup file is not deleted